# How do I change the index of a pandas dataframe object so as not to get null values in the dataframe entries?

Tags: pandas

I do not seem to know what the issue is when I combined three dataframes into one and tried changing the index of the combined dataframe. The following is what I have done:

1) I first combined (or Concatenated) three dataframes into a 'combo' dataframe. Below is an excerpt ('TSP_JuMP_Obtained_Solu') of one of the three. The index goes from 0-9 for all the three datafames as well as the combined.

[image]

2) I then used the following line of code to combine them:

```
f_solu_tsp = pd.concat([list_TSP,list_Scenario1,list_Scenario2], axis=1, 
sort=True)
```

3) I subsequently used the followine line of code to change the index of the combined dataframe (df_solu_tsp):

```
df_solu_tsp = df_solu_tsp.reindex(proTy_uniq_list)
```

NB: 'proTy_uniq_list' is a list with membership as shown below:

```
[u'lau15', u'gr17', u'fri26', u'bays29', u'dantzig42', u'KATRINA_38', 
u'HARVEY_50', u'HARVEY_100', u'HARVEY_200', u'HARVEY_415']
```

Below is the result of the combined dataframe (df_solu_tsp ):

[image]

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Please add an example dataframe so we can reproduce the steps you described.

Comment: If you're trying to replace the integer index with the custom list of strings, is `df_solu_tsp = df_solu_tsp.set_index(proTy_uniq_list)` what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks, Pete. This - df_solu_tsp = df_solu_tsp.set_index([proTy_uniq_list]) worked.

Answer (score 1):

Without having example `DataFrame` I will try to answer as good as possible:

**Solution 1**

As Peter Leimbigler mentioned in the comments:

```
df_solu_tsp = df_solu_tsp.set_index(proTy_uniq_list)
```

Which replaces your original index with the new index which is in this case an equal length list.

**Solution 2**

As mentioned in the [`pandas docs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)

```
df_solu_tsp.set_index([pd.Index(proTy_uniq_list), 'proTy'])
```

**Solution 3**

I see that you're creating a dataframe from three lists, so we can go a step back and create your data in one go:

```
f_solu_tsp  = pd.DataFrame({'TSP_JuMP_Obtained_Solu': list_TSP,
                            'Scenario1': list_Scenario1,
                            'Scenario2': list_Scenario2}, index=proTy_uniq_list)
```

**Example solution 3**

```
data1 = ['hi', 'goodbye']
data2 = ['hello', 'bye']

idx = ['arriving', 'leaving']

df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': data1,
                   'column2': data2}, index=idx)

print(df)
          column1 column2
arriving       hi   hello
leaving   goodbye     bye
```